# Google SDTT: "The property 'availability' is not recognized by Google for an object of type Product"

Tags: schema.org, microdata

Situation: need to add the `availability` property to a product page.

Schema.org recommends this format for Microdata:

```html
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />In stock
```

I'm combining it with the code on our site:

```html
<li>
    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o">&nbsp;
        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
        <span>In Stock</span>
    </i>
</li>
```

Problem: Google Structured Data Testing Tool reports:

> `http://schema.org/InStock` (The property `availability` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `Product`.)

Is this a code issue?
Or am I missing some Schema/Google "wrapper" for the `availability` property?

Answer (score 5):

Ack. Figured it out. `availability` has to be inside an `Offer`:

```html
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">              
  <h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o">&nbsp;
          <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
          <span>In Stock</span>
        </i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </h1>
</div>
```