# In the MusicEvent schema, why is the jobTitle property within Person not recognized by Google?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

The [docs](https://schema.org/MusicEvent) for the MusicEvent schema show the property `performer` can be of type `Organization` or `Person`, with the description:

> A performer at the event—for example, a presenter, musician, musical
>   group or actor. Supersedes performers.

The [docs](https://schema.org/Person) for the Person schema show the property `jobTitle` with the description:

> The job title of the person (for example, Financial Manager).

But when used like this:

```
<article itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicEvent">

   <!-- other stuff -->

   <p itemprop="performer" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
      <b itemprop="name">Constantine Kitsopoulos</b>, 
         <span itemprop="jobTitle">conductor</span>
    </p>

   <!-- other stuff -->

</article>
```

the Google Structured Data Testing tool shows the warning:

> The property jobTitle is not recognized by Google for an object of
>   type MusicEvent.

In a [related schema.org question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313384/google-sdtt-the-property-availability-is-not-recognized-by-google-for-an-obj), the answer was the property was not wrapped correctly. I've double and triple-checked the HTML to be sure the `jobTitle` itemprop is wrapped within the `Person` schema tags, which are wrapped within the `MusicEvent` schema tags. Is there something I am misunderstanding, or are things that are valid in MusicEvent schema without being valid to Google's tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microdata, each item is required to have an `itemscope` attribute. The `itemtype` can be specified in addition (it’s optional).

Your snippet with the two `itemscope` attributes that were missing:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicEvent">

  <p itemprop="performer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <b itemprop="name">Constantine Kitsopoulos</b>, 
    <span itemprop="jobTitle">conductor</span>
  </p>

</article>
```

Google’s SDTT recognizes it correctly:

```
@type MusicEvent
performer   
  @type Person
  name Constantine Kitsopoulos
  jobTitle conductor
```

(The warnings/errors it reports aren’t problems with your markup; these are just things that are recommended/required for getting one of Google’s rich results.)

Comment: Excellent catch. Thank you.